# Is there any way to rent a place to house my server?

Tags: linux

Is there any way of paying somebody to house my server (which I physically own) and connect it to the internet? Is this a thing? Preferably this would be cheaper than renting a server.

Comment: Yes, these are called colocation services, and you can find them by the thousands by shopping on the Internet.

Comment: I'm one of those voting for reopening.  To me, this isn't a shopping question.  The OP isn't asking for the names and numbers of some colo providers; she's asking about the whole concept of a colo provider, and I think we can give some useful advice on how to differentiate between them in our answers (as Miles has already started to do).  Might just be me, though.

Comment: But what about profesional capacity? That sounds more like "clueless dude in basement" than professional administrator.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. It's called co-location (or colo) and, if you are in a major city, you are likely to find many options. You get what you pay for.

Comment: And google helps. "Housing a server" - google would answer. Anyhow, google is needed to find regional offers anyway.